# Image previews in one line - in center and proportional

Tags: html, css

I am trying to format one-line preview of photo gallery. It can be displayed on different pages with different number of pictures. There are two possible scenarios A) pictures fit in screen B) there are too many pictures. In A, I’d like pictures in the middle of screen with small padding. In B, I’d like every picture to get proportional part of available space. I can serve scenario A with code 1 and scenario B with code 2, but I’ve been unable to serve both scenarios it with one universal code.

I’d like to have pure html+css solution. I can imagine to handle it with javascript if there is no other solution.

Remarks: Pictures in B should be rather trimmed than resized. In real solution, there will DIVs with display:table and so, rather than html table.

1)

```css
/*same*/
#container {
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 120px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: red;
}

/*different*/
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  A (OK):
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="" /></td>
      <td><img src="" /></td>
      <td><img src="" /></td>
      <tr>
  </table>
  B (not OK - overflowing):
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="" /></td>
      <td><img src="" /></td>
      <td><img src="" /></td>
      <td><img src="" /></td>
      <td><img src="" /></td>
      <td><img src="" /></td>
      <td><img src="" /></td>
      <tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

2)

```css
/*same*/
#container {
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 120px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: red;
}

/*different*/
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100% !important;
  table-layout:fixed;
}

td {
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  A (not OK - using whole width, spaces too big):
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="" /></td>
      <td><img src="" /></td>
      <td><img src="" /></td>
      <tr>
  </table>
  B (OK):
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="" /></td>
      <td><img src="" /></td>
      <td><img src="" /></td>
      <td><img src="" /></td>
      <td><img src="" /></td>
      <td><img src="" /></td>
      <td><img src="" /></td>
      <tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried looking at flexbox?

Comment: something like this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a trivial flexbox job:

```css
/*same*/
#container {
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 120px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: red;
}

/*different*/
section {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}

section div{
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  A (OK):
  <section>
      <div><img src="" /></div>
      <div><img src="" /></div>
      <div><img src="" /></div>
  </section>
  B (OK):
  <section>
      <div><img src="" /></div>
      <div><img src="" /></div>
      <div><img src="" /></div>
      <div><img src="" /></div>
      <div><img src="" /></div>
      <div><img src="" /></div>
      <div><img src="" /></div>
  </section>
</div>
```